# How to get the type of values from a JDBC query?

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job that takes in a user query, executes that query to find the selected items, and then I want to insert those items into another database. The problem is that I have to convert elements like dates from the resulting query to insert them again. How can I tell the type of the values returned from the query?

This is what I use to read the items which works properly.

```
   @Bean("querySelectiveItems")
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader querySelectiveItems(@Qualifier("selectiveSourceDatabase") DataSource dataSource,
                                                    @Value("#{jobExecutionContext[" + EtlConfiguration.JOB_PARM_MIGRATION_CONFIG + "]}") MigrationDefinition migrationDefinition
    ) {
        JdbcCursorItemReader reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setSql(migrationDefinition.getMigrations().getTable().getQuery());
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setRowMapper(new ColumnMapRowMapper());
        log.info("Queried for items");
        return reader;
    }
```

The following is what I wrote to write to the destination database. The problem is that the values I have to insert are unknown because they are the result of a user query. For example if there is a datatype in my insert statement I must have a TO_DATE around the date value. Is there a way to do this?

```
    @Component
    @Lazy
    class InsertSelectedItems implements ItemWriter<Map<String, Object>> {


        private MigrationDefinition migrationDefinition;

        private JdbcTemplate destinationTemplate;

        public void setDestinationTemplate(JdbcTemplate destinationTemplate) {
            this.destinationTemplate = destinationTemplate;
        }

        public void setMigrationDefinition(MigrationDefinition migrationDefinition) {
            this.migrationDefinition = migrationDefinition;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(List<? extends Map<String, Object>> items) throws Exception {
            ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
            System.out.println(items);
            for (Map<String, Object> map : items) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    columns.add(entry.getKey());
                    values.add(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
                }
            }

            String sql = String.format("%s ( %s ) VALUES ( %s ) ",
                    migrationDefinition.getMigrations().getTable().getInsert(),
                    String.join(",", columns),
                    String.join(",", values));

            log.info(sql);
            destinationTemplate.update(sql);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of string-ifying the values, you should use a prepared statement and ? placeholders, and `setObject()` to set them, which is required to work for all column types.

Comment: what about null values with unknown types?

Comment: I get a `Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of com.asfasf.infra.batch.libdb.LibDbEtlConfiguration$InsertSelectedItems$$Lambda$465/152673826. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
 at `

Comment: I have no idea about Spring but you can certainly get the column types from JDBC. It seems to me you should be operating down at the JDBC level for this, not the Spring layer.